# Imagem responsiva, não redimenciona corretamente

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Estou desenvolvendo um *site*, e uma imagem não está redimensionando como eu esperava, tenho a imagem:

```
<div class="cover">
    <div class="cover-image" style="background-image : url('http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-AycDlsjqzZg/TwNAOJgtvWI/AAAAAAAAAsU/7J9HDoXhHLs/s1600/bouken-ni+logo+01.png')"></div>
</div>
```

e tenho minhas classe CSS para redimensionar:

```
.cover {
 padding: 30px 15px;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 color: inherit;
 background-color: #eeeeee;
 margin-bottom: 0px !important;
 padding: 0px 0px;
 background-color: transparent;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
-webkit-align-items: center;
 align-items: center;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 height: 70%;
}
.cover .cover-image {    
z-index: -1;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
min-height: 30%;
height: 100%;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;

}
```

Comment: redimensionar como ? como você quer que ela fique ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ddLaqyvq/

Comment: O controle de redimensionamento é feito no CSS. Mas você tem que analisar se o tamanho da imagem está bom. Seu width está 100% você pode aumentar seu height também. Mas ainda está um pouco difícil de entender...

Comment: @roger seguinte eu pretendo colocar qualquer imagem. Desta forma quero deixar ela redimensionando automaticamente

Answer (score 1):

É o seguinte André a propriedade (background-size) quando você passar alguma unidade de medida em % por exemplo ele faz o redimensionamento mantendo o aspect ratio (proporção) da imagem com base na largura e altura do box pai.
Agora se você usa a palavra-chave (contain/cover) ele redimensionar proporcional mas trabalhando de forma diferente.
**Contain:** Maior dimensão ocupa toda extensão do box;
**Cover:** Menor dimensão ocupa toda extensão do box.

Agora você escolhe o melhor layout amigo.